# How to attach and show image in mail using Asp.NET?

Tags: asp.net, email, html-email

I want to send email with an image attachment but the image must not be hosted on the server. I will attach the image show it in my html e-mail (with img src...). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into using LinkedResource ? :  http://aspalliance.com/1411_Using_LinkedResource_Class_for_Sending_HTML_Email_in_NET_20.5